# Looking for dataset: metadata about news articles, spanning 15+ years

Tags: database, dataset

Does anyone know of a dataset that has metadata about news articles?

Basic dataset requirements:

1. 100k+ news articles
2. Covers 5+ publications
3. Spans 15+ years of articles
4. Metadata about each article *with author names + year published*
5. Must be sourced legitimately (no TOS-breaking scraped data)

I've looked through many potential sources. Here are some examples:

- [New York Times](https://help.nytimes.com/hc/en-us/articles/115014772767-Archives) and [the Guardian](https://open-platform.theguardian.com/) data archives -- fail criterion 2
- [News headlines of India](https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/india-headlines-news-dataset) -- fails criterion 4 and possibly 5
- Various APIs for streaming news (Eventregistry, WebHose.io)  -- all seem to be made for recent news, so they fail criterion 3
- [Reuter's data dumps](https://trec.nist.gov/data/reuters/reuters.html) -- fails criterion 3

Comment: This is not really a programming question.  You might have better luck asking this on [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @G5W, posting there instead.